# Why should I prefer alpha blending to alpha testing?

Tags: mobile, opengl-es, gpu, alphablending, alpha-transparency

I've read some articles about tile-based architecture.

I understand alpha blending is not that bad in this architecture. But I really don't see why alpha blending is better than alpha testing.

**Alpha Testing**

1. Hardware HSR: no
2. Sorting needed(CPU): **no**
3. Redundant shading: almost? (all?)
4. Z-Write: barely cost

**Alpha Blending**

1. Hardware HSR: no
2. Sorting needed(CPU): **yes**
3. Redundant shading: all
4. Z-Write: no
5. Blending Operation: barely cost

I'm not sure some pixels of alpha testing may be culled by other alpha testing pixels (Alpha Testing No.3).

Alpha blending is definitely slower than alpha testing in my project (because of batching problem, not by rendering cost itself).

Anyway, I don't know why alpha blending would be better than alpha testing in general cases. Many reasons why alpha testing is slow apply to alpha blending also.

Comment: They are not the same thing. Alpha testing is a binary test that rejects fragments that do not meet certain requirements (based on alpha value). Alpha blending takes shaded fragments and blends them with pixels in the frame buffer to produce a new pixel. It is worth mentioning that unlike stencil/depth tests, alpha testing cannot be optimized early on - it is always performed **after** shading. They are so different that you can apply both to a fragment. Blending adds overhead because instead of writing directly to the frame buffer, it has to blend with whatever is already in the frame buffer.

Comment: I know they are different. My question is why everyone say one should use alpha blending **instead of** alpha testing.
And FYI as long as in tile-based architecture, blending overhead barely exists because it blends with (very fast) tile screen not (slow) frame buffer.

Comment: As I was hinting at earlier, alpha testing breaks early fragment tests. When you use alpha testing, shading has to be evaluated completely before the result is known. That is, the depth of a primitive is not known until after the alpha test. This is terrible for tile-based architectures.